# Android: How disable EditText depending focus

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I'm doing a app wich have two EditText. What I wanna do is, if you click on one and write on it, the other must erease anything It has and only shows the hint string. I'm triying doing it witha a check method that does:

```
if(celsius.isFocused()){

        faren.setText(faren.getHint().toString());
    }
    if(faren.isFocused()){

        celsius.setText(celsius.getHint().toString());
    }
```

Then I call this method within the onCreate() method, but of course It only checks one time, and if use that checkMethod inside a loop, the app doesn't show anthing, It freezes. An suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html).

```
faren.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus)
            celcius.setText(""); // This will automatically show the hint text
    }
});
```